# Detecting multiple instances of application on LAN in Swift and C# as well

Tags: c#, swift, macos, networking

I am looking for a code strategy to be able to detect if multiple instances of my app are being ran across a LAN. I have tried searching for ideas but nothing pegs it and I ran out of search queries that make sense.

I am mostly starting off with just Swift code, but eventually will want to include C# under windows.

I suspect I have to generate a packet of somesort to broadcast itself across the LAN with a unique identifier and it detects that broadcast with identifiers that don't match?

I am not looking for a premade app that does this. I want to embed it into this code.

I don't want to block multiples from running, I just want to grab a statistics of use and send that out to my server that hosts the web interface for this app. (This part I have no issues with)

Comment: I really like and appreciate both answers from Andy and Jeroen. Another dev on my project commented that users may get weird about a phone home. So I was hesitant to go much further with this. But both answers give me an idea to allow a resource share between applications on the same LAN. I also figure since I had a hard time finding even a search query to address this, that leaving this up as is even if I don't intend to go further with the "feature" I asked about may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, you could use UDP for this. Just broadcast a 'I am here' message. From there, you could setup a TCP connection to communicate between the applications.

---

After rereading your last paragraph, you could detect 2 instances on the same lan at your server, because they are all using the same (external) IP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort of [rendezvous server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_protocol), a simple version of it adapted for your needs. You'd need to run a server on well known address listening to incoming connections and each instance of your application would register with it (e.g. by just connecting) on startup.

Broadcasting would be simpler but has also some limitations like difficulties to broadcast between subnets or wider.